# USB wont mount persistence after kernel panic

Tags: mount

I have a USB drive that I was running with persistence.  Apparently a Kernel Panic crashed my system.  In terminal when typing 'ls' I was getting an input/output error and it showed nothing.  When I rebooted thats when I was informed that I was experiencing Kernel Panic.  Now when I plug the USB into any computer windows and or otherwise it refuses to mount the drive due to the persistence partition.  I can not format, and after I get the error cant mount persistence the drive disappears the system can't see it.  I tried using the disk-utility and also dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg and also with /dev/null.  There is not a lot of mileage on this drive so I want to rescue it if possible.  Are there any other methods ? It is only visible to the system for less than 30 seconds before it just vanishes. I even raced and was able to format every partition except 'persistence' because it appears to be mounted but isn't.

Comment: Clarify your question by placing it into more context. With "persistence", do you mean a live USB session that allows to save user data?

Comment: Yes, and its not limited I can use the remainder of my drive if I wanted to.  Sometimes when making a persistence Live USB you can only save 4gb.  That being said it has somehow rendered the drive unusable because of the Kernel Panic.  The drive is 16gb, partitioned as follows : the ISO/ the FS/ and 13gb remaining as persistence.  I know the drive is small but if this ever happens to a larger drive I want to know how to fix it.  Thanks for your help so far.